# Solution of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Determine   how many    solutions the   following   system  have?

$\begin{cases}~\dfrac{5}{4} x -\dfrac{2}{3} y - 3 = 0\\
~\dfrac{1}{4} x + \dfrac{5}{3} y - 6 = 0\end{cases}$

The correct answer is: "one solution".

How did they determine this?

When I apply the method of  elimination to determine it, I come to the answer "infinitely many solutions".

Can someone explain me why the correct answer is "one solution"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use the elimination method to find a solution, the equation we have after we eliminate one variable tell us the nature of the solution.

**If there is infinitly many solutions**, we will have an equation such as
$$0x +0y+0=0$$
It mean that the two equations are the same and no mather what value we gave to $x$, there is a value $y$ such that $(x,y)$ satisfy both equation.

**If there are no solution**, we Will have an equation such as$$0x+0y+c=0 \qquad c\neq0$$
No mather what values we gave to $x$ and $y$, this equation will never be true.

After we eliminate a variable, if the coefficient of the other is different of $0$, then the **solution is unique.**

In your example
$$\begin{cases}~\dfrac{5}{4} x -\dfrac{2}{3} y - 3 = 0\\
~\dfrac{1}{4} x + \dfrac{5}{3} y - 6 = 0\end{cases}$$
Multiplying the second équation by $5$
$$\begin{cases}~\dfrac{5}{4} x -\dfrac{2}{3} y - 3 = 0\\
~\dfrac{5}{4} x + \dfrac{25}{3} y - 30= 0\end{cases}$$
Substract both equations give
$$0x-\frac{27}{3}y+27=0$$
Thus the solution is unique and $y=3$. By replacing this value in one of the equation, we find that $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the system is given in matrix form by
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 5/4 & -2/3 \\ 1/4 & 5/3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\6\end{bmatrix}, $$
and
$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} 5/4 & -2/3 \\ 1/4 & 5/3 \end{bmatrix}
= \frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{9}{4} \not= 0, $$
so that the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is it possible to use the method of elimination to determine it?

Comment: You can use Gaußian elimination to compute the determinant… However,  for a $2{\times}2$ determinant, using the formula is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The *algorithmic way*:
Use row operations on   the augmented matrix, until is left-hand side is the $2{\times}2$ unit matrix. The solution is the last column:
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rr|r}
\frac 54&-\frac23 &3 \\
\frac14&\frac53& 6
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1&-\frac73 &-3 \\
\frac14&\frac53& 6
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1&-\frac73 &-3 \\
0&\frac94& \frac{27}4
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]\rightsquigarrow
&\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1&-\frac73 &-3 \\
0& 1& 3
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 &0 & \color{red}4 \\
0& 1& \color{red}3
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}